# ignore provided input in python

Tags: python, shell

I have python code which calls a shell script (get_list.sh) and this shell script calls one .txt file which is having the entires like :

```
aaf:hfhfh:notusable:type: - city_name
hhf:hgyt:usable:type: - city_name
llf:hdgt:used:type: - city_name
```

and when I providing the input like after running the python code :

code for providing the input :

```
List = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list  : ')).upper().strip()

hhf|aaf|llf
```

code for getting the output :

```
if List:
            try:
                    cmd = "/home/dponnura/get_list.sh -s " + "\"" + List + "\""
                    selfP = commands.getoutput(cmd).strip()

            except OSError:
                    print bcolors.FAIL + "Could not invoke Pod Details Script. " + bcolors.ENDC
```

it shows me the output as :

```
hhf detils : hfhfh:notusable:type: - city_name
aaf details : hgyt:usable:type: - city_name
llf details : hdgt:used:type: - city_name
```

What my requirnment is, if I passes the input after execution of python code and if my enties are not present in .txt file it should show me the output as :

if I provide the input as :

```
hhf|aaf|llf|ggg
```

then for 'ggg' it should show me like :

```
'ggg' is wrong input
hhf detils : hfhfh:notusable:type: - city_name
aaf details : hgyt:usable:type: - city_name
llf details : hdgt:used:type: - city_name
```

Could you please let me know how can I do this in python or shell?

Comment: Please fix this to be readable (especially indenting the code as code blocks, with the `{}` button). Also, you seem to be missing most of the desired output ("it should show me the output as :" and then nothing…), which makes it kind of hard to figure out what you want.

Comment: Please review once more if its readable now.

Comment: Is `hhf|aaf|llf` part of the code for providing the input? If not, what is it? And meanwhile, you still have "… if should show me the output as : " with nothing after it farther down.

Comment: As a side note, why are you calling `str` on the result of `raw_input`? What were you expecting `raw_input` to give you, if not a `str`?

Comment: Thanks Abarnert


hhf|aaf|llf is not the part of the code. It is the input provided by me. 
if should show me the output as : 

'ggg' is wrong input
hhf detils : hfhfh:notusable:type: - city_name
aaf details : hgyt:usable:type: - city_name
llf details : hdgt:used:type: - city_name

If I provide the O/P : 

hhf|aaf|llf|ggg

and 'ggg' is not present in .txt file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your task can ( and I think have to ) be implemented in pure Python. Below is one of possible variants of its solution using just Python, without external scripts or libraries

```
pipelst = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list  : ')).split('|')
filepath = 'test.txt'   # specify path to your file here
for lns in open(filepath):
    split_pipe = lns.split(':', 1)
    if split_pipe[0] in pipelst:
        print split_pipe[0], ' details : ', split_pipe[1]
        pipelst.remove(split_pipe[0])
for lns in pipelst : print lns,' is wrong input'
```

As you can see, it is a short, simple and clear.

Comment: Can someone explain what is wrong with my answer and why it's down voted?

Answer (score 0):

Here is this done in Python, without calling get_list.sh

```
import sys,re
List = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list  : ')).strip().split('|')
for linE in open(sys.argv[1]):
    for l1 in List:
        m1 = re.match(l1+':(.+)',linE)
        if m1:
            print l1,'details :',m1.group(1)
            List.remove(l1)
            break
for l1 in List : print l1,'is wrong input'
```

Usage :
python script.py textFile.txt

Comment: I need to call shell script :(

Comment: Hi sidharth,

I am getting below error while appending above code :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main_menu.py", line 967, in <module>
    pPODName()
  File "./main_menu.py", line 900, in pPODName
    for linE in open(sys.argv[1]):
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: u have to give the textFile.txt as argument to the script